# I want to create a ViewController where user can change there existing password. I m using Parse API

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, xcode5, parse-platform

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser]; 

// I can see the details of the users when this is called including password

if (user) {

    if ([_login_txtpassword.text isEqualToString:user[@"UserPasswrod"]]) {
        user[@"userPassword"] = _login_txtnewpassword.text;
        [user saveInBackground];
        NSLog(@"done");
    }
}
```

this code is not working.... i have put blocks to test my code ... it doesnt pass the if statement

A little conflict in my concepts related parse (so consider me as a noob)
P.S i have read the documentation and search internet but couldnt find a solution.

Many Many thanks in advcance

Comment: What's your question .. ?

Comment: this code is not working.... i have put blocks to test my code ... it doesnt pass the if statement ... if ([_login_txtpassword.text isEqualToString:user[@"UserPasswrod"]])

Comment: You did misspell UserPassword, you have wrod instead of word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is to try to log the user in with the old password, then set the new password if successful.  (notice this code uses the parse User `password` attribute, not `@"userPassword"` as in the OP code, which won't work under any circumstances)...

```
NSString *username = [PFUser currentUser].username;
NSString *oldPassword = self.oldPasswordTextField.text;
NSString *newPassword = self.newPasswordTextField.text;

[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:oldPassword
  block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (user) {
        user.password = newPassword;
        [user saveInBackground];
    } else {
        // update UI to tell user that the old password is incorrect
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't override the password of the current user directly from your ViewController. The user should request a new password, that will by sent to his/her email by Parse.

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *userEmail = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", currentUser.email];
[PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:userEmail];
```

or

```
[PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:self.userEmailTextfield.text];
```

Comment: actually i wanted the user to do it on the app not on mail ;)